# SQL query equivalent in python to: delete only one identical record in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anti-join

**Problem-stmt:**
To Delete a column from a table[MDF] based on a condition[OP_DIRECTIVE = 'D'] from a different table[INC].
Both the tables have identical columns.

I am looking for a SQL Equivalent Query in Python to Delete one identical record even if there are multiple records match the **DELETE** condition

I've written the same in SQL [working]:-
Approach to my solution: Copy unmatched rows to a work table, then truncate the original table and replace with contents of the work table. One way to identify unmatched rows would be to tag each of the input rows in a set of duplicates with a unique number, something like this:

```sql
INSERT work_table SELECT MI.col1, MI.col2, ...
FROM 
  (SELECT M.*,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <join cols> ORDER BY <some col(s)>) AS ROWNUM
   FROM MORTALITY M) MI
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT I.*, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <join cols> ORDER BY <some col(s)>) AS ROWNUM
   FROM INC_MORTALITY I
   WHERE OP_DIRECTIVE='D') INC
ON MI.join_col1 = INC.join_col1
AND MI.join_col2 = INC.join_col2
... all the columns except for 'OP_DIRECTIVE'
AND MI.ROWNUM = INC.ROWNUM
WHERE INC.ROWNUM IS NULL /* "anti-join" keeps only unmatched rows */
;
DELETE FROM MORTALITY;
INSERT MORTALITY SELECT * FROM work_table;
```

What i've tried:

```py
import os
import time
import pandas as pd

filePath = '/Users/test_files'
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%-H%M%S")
fileName = ‘left_join' + timestr + '.txt'

if os.path.exists(filePath):
        MDF = pd.read_csv(“mdf.txt", sep='|')
        INC = pd.read_csv(“inc.txt”, sep='|')
        
       result = MDF.merge(
                    INC_D,
                    on=['data_source','dd_imp_flag','dob','dod','death_verification','gender_probability','gender','token_1','token_2','token_4','token_5','token_7','token_16','token_key'],
                    how = 'left',
                    suffixes=('', '_delme'))
        cols = result.columns.difference(MDF.columns)
        result = result.loc[result[cols].isnull().all(axis=1), MDF.columns.tolist()]

        result.to_csv(os.path.join(filePath, fileName), sep="|", index=False)  # remove header=None if header is needed
        print("Data export successful.")
else:
    print("File path does not exist.")
```

But this deletes all the records matching 'D' as an indicator, clearly i am missing `ROW_NUMBER` here, so i am wondering how to achieve it in python

*MDF-previously*

```
data_source|op_directive|dd_imp_flag|dod|dob|death_verification|gender_probability|gender|token_1|token_2|token_4|token_5|token_7|token_16|token_key
OBIT^SSA|A|1|1931-12-06|1978-03-31|5|0.6735|M|3i5HbesGaxZKeHTAzQkeDskr3YTEyMhcm2zpOQUexog=|UqskLHepjFVSIYGTlpsezOi30eTDh4VrX9H87ynifX6=|6E8hQBwm9Ylwszv6LJwyGN1TF18y8hRubFHe4pLwE03=|SoU4pSpEFZhtUROME0rFwlqnRDb5gfHlcCnlTZLuPQv=|yc499QG3ItyqRtqr8bKFtZ4WRaOBwAZzP5Pmd1ChTUF=|zJBxzxwqZVY66finpsmtRfuzBqeQ2N0FhMGyWmoxB07=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
OBIT^SSA|A|1|1931-12-06|1978-03-31|5|0.6735|M|3i5HbesGaxZKeHTAzQkeDskr3YTEyMhcm2zpOQUexog=|UqskLHepjFVSIYGTlpsezOi30eTDh4VrX9H87ynifX6=|6E8hQBwm9Ylwszv6LJwyGN1TF18y8hRubFHe4pLwE03=|SoU4pSpEFZhtUROME0rFwlqnRDb5gfHlcCnlTZLuPQv=|yc499QG3ItyqRtqr8bKFtZ4WRaOBwAZzP5Pmd1ChTUF=|zJBxzxwqZVY66finpsmtRfuzBqeQ2N0FhMGyWmoxB07=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
SSA|A|0|1940-12-01|1859-09-01|3|1.0|F|Vznnb7W7VcSvM6bdKbDLyKXcv/UK9FYxfQEWSf7WU1s=|2ye4lajQ4v2lzl5P0sJnUExn8uMMjjWw3vInwUFjx50=|geZFT7Ea5O8rwGwJi17dL9EggYY+ahpfEv5hqz8f/K4=|cT8lopT3v+qvNykrv5N0/hNQdVzEBWt0wz8V01L197Q=|fSkPNkTewOiC+o7ahtH/6YvOx6MJ2Tr36gHyZYBFiNU=|cyusBFir8H19NvWjBYSriCIivL2KVqzFtJkSWSciYFM=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
SSA|A|0|1940-12-01|1859-10-01|3|0.0|F|4pxtVDIKcDdiSZqgMNlI5rILQCmm0RhgScJ2E84+BwI=|KyNwahEN6lCvxGBxAOXjYO/QM0Z0QcfI7kPtcEITS4s=|wzyHav4A370qgBk8wPn2AaJyMHMtdFJDCTFhLog9wkI=|hohND7ZFlO9ug14Vei2ESXNy9eqYT47DbiI9J2v+ljQ=|8Plp87L0cC6gdlVbaE0YYzSoe46oIbR/YccdfFGtgd8=|Sb6pUg1X7R7nJONwRrMbWYZ8rMi2TRSkriYHawx2vNE=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
SSA|A|0|1940-12-01|1859-10-01|3|0.0|F|4pxtVDIKcDdiSZqgMNlI5rILQCmm0RhgScJ2E84+BwI=|KyNwahEN6lCvxGBxAOXjYO/QM0Z0QcfI7kPtcEITS4s=|wzyHav4A370qgBk8wPn2AaJyMHMtdFJDCTFhLog9wkI=|hohND7ZFlO9ug14Vei2ESXNy9eqYT47DbiI9J2v+ljQ=|8Plp87L0cC6gdlVbaE0YYzSoe46oIbR/YccdfFGtgd8=|Sb6pUg1X7R7nJONwRrMbWYZ8rMi2TRSkriYHawx2vNE=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
SSA|A|0|1940-12-01|1859-10-01|3|0.0|F|4pxtVDIKcDdiSZqgMNlI5rILQCmm0RhgScJ2E84+BwI=|KyNwahEN6lCvxGBxAOXjYO/QM0Z0QcfI7kPtcEITS4s=|wzyHav4A370qgBk8wPn2AaJyMHMtdFJDCTFhLog9wkI=|hohND7ZFlO9ug14Vei2ESXNy9eqYT47DbiI9J2v+ljQ=|8Plp87L0cC6gdlVbaE0YYzSoe46oIbR/YccdfFGtgd8=|Sb6pUg1X7R7nJONwRrMbWYZ8rMi2TRSkriYHawx2vNE=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

*INC*

```
data_source|op_directive|dd_imp_flag|dod|dob|death_verification|gender_probability|gender|token_1|token_2|token_4|token_5|token_7|token_16|token_key
OBIT^SSA|D|1|1931-12-06|1978-03-31|5|0.6735|M|3i5HbesGaxZKeHTAzQkeDskr3YTEyMhcm2zpOQUexog=|UqskLHepjFVSIYGTlpsezOi30eTDh4VrX9H87ynifX6=|6E8hQBwm9Ylwszv6LJwyGN1TF18y8hRubFHe4pLwE03=|SoU4pSpEFZhtUROME0rFwlqnRDb5gfHlcCnlTZLuPQv=|yc499QG3ItyqRtqr8bKFtZ4WRaOBwAZzP5Pmd1ChTUF=|zJBxzxwqZVY66finpsmtRfuzBqeQ2N0FhMGyWmoxB07=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
SSA|D|0|1940-12-01|1859-09-01|3|1.0|F|Vznnb7W7VcSvM6bdKbDLyKXcv/UK9FYxfQEWSf7WU1s=|2ye4lajQ4v2lzl5P0sJnUExn8uMMjjWw3vInwUFjx50=|geZFT7Ea5O8rwGwJi17dL9EggYY+ahpfEv5hqz8f/K4=|cT8lopT3v+qvNykrv5N0/hNQdVzEBWt0wz8V01L197Q=|fSkPNkTewOiC+o7ahtH/6YvOx6MJ2Tr36gHyZYBFiNU=|cyusBFir8H19NvWjBYSriCIivL2KVqzFtJkSWSciYFM=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
SSA|D|0|1940-12-01|1859-10-01|3|0.0|F|4pxtVDIKcDdiSZqgMNlI5rILQCmm0RhgScJ2E84+BwI=|KyNwahEN6lCvxGBxAOXjYO/QM0Z0QcfI7kPtcEITS4s=|wzyHav4A370qgBk8wPn2AaJyMHMtdFJDCTFhLog9wkI=|hohND7ZFlO9ug14Vei2ESXNy9eqYT47DbiI9J2v+ljQ=|8Plp87L0cC6gdlVbaE0YYzSoe46oIbR/YccdfFGtgd8=|Sb6pUg1X7R7nJONwRrMbWYZ8rMi2TRSkriYHawx2vNE=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

*MDF-after-updates-expected output*

```
data_source|op_directive|dd_imp_flag|dod|dob|death_verification|gender_probability|gender|token_1|token_2|token_4|token_5|token_7|token_16|token_key
OBIT^SSA|A|1|1931-12-06|1978-03-31|5|0.6735|M|3i5HbesGaxZKeHTAzQkeDskr3YTEyMhcm2zpOQUexog=|UqskLHepjFVSIYGTlpsezOi30eTDh4VrX9H87ynifX6=|6E8hQBwm9Ylwszv6LJwyGN1TF18y8hRubFHe4pLwE03=|SoU4pSpEFZhtUROME0rFwlqnRDb5gfHlcCnlTZLuPQv=|yc499QG3ItyqRtqr8bKFtZ4WRaOBwAZzP5Pmd1ChTUF=|zJBxzxwqZVY66finpsmtRfuzBqeQ2N0FhMGyWmoxB07=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
SSA|A|0|1940-12-01|1859-10-01|3|0.0|F|4pxtVDIKcDdiSZqgMNlI5rILQCmm0RhgScJ2E84+BwI=|KyNwahEN6lCvxGBxAOXjYO/QM0Z0QcfI7kPtcEITS4s=|wzyHav4A370qgBk8wPn2AaJyMHMtdFJDCTFhLog9wkI=|hohND7ZFlO9ug14Vei2ESXNy9eqYT47DbiI9J2v+ljQ=|8Plp87L0cC6gdlVbaE0YYzSoe46oIbR/YccdfFGtgd8=|Sb6pUg1X7R7nJONwRrMbWYZ8rMi2TRSkriYHawx2vNE=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
SSA|A|0|1940-12-01|1859-10-01|3|0.0|F|4pxtVDIKcDdiSZqgMNlI5rILQCmm0RhgScJ2E84+BwI=|KyNwahEN6lCvxGBxAOXjYO/QM0Z0QcfI7kPtcEITS4s=|wzyHav4A370qgBk8wPn2AaJyMHMtdFJDCTFhLog9wkI=|hohND7ZFlO9ug14Vei2ESXNy9eqYT47DbiI9J2v+ljQ=|8Plp87L0cC6gdlVbaE0YYzSoe46oIbR/YccdfFGtgd8=|Sb6pUg1X7R7nJONwRrMbWYZ8rMi2TRSkriYHawx2vNE=|cigna-datavant_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

Comment: if you are looking to do a rownumber in pandas, then have a look at [groupby.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

Comment: you don't have the row `SSA|D|0|1940-12-01|1859-09-01|3|1.0|F|...` in your expected result, while it is both in MDF and INC, can you explain why you did not keep it?

Comment: @Ben.T yes correct, because INC gives us all the rows that has to be deleted from MDF[main history file], so this record was common in both the df's[except for 'op_directive' indicator column] and it was a 'SINGLE' occurrence so it has to be deleted from the main file, Hope you got what i am trying to say?

Comment: @Ben.T To be accurate, this is the scenario i wanted to achieve: Delete rows in the master table[MDF] which have a OP_DIRECTIVE = 'D' as the operation in the weekly update[INC]. For a given delete row, you should delete a single row in the master table which matches the delete record on all fields aside from the “D” operation column. Warning: please ensure you only delete, or mark as deleted, one record, even if more than one historical record fully matches this new delete record - [Note: these are the exact words from Business :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your explanation in the comments and the sentence *"Warning: please ensure you only delete, or mark as deleted, one record, even if more than one historical record fully matches this new delete record"*, I believe a simple way to achieve your result is to use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) that would mark as `True` all duplicated rows, starting the second duplicates

```
result.loc[result[cols].isnull().all(axis=1)
           |result.duplicated(subset=MDF.columns, keep='first'), # add this condition
           MDF.columns.tolist()]
```

Comment: okay, let me try that, BTW thanks for taking time to look into this :)

Comment: WOW!! it worked, this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Ben, appreciate it

Comment: @Mando basically, `duplicated` will consider `True` any duplicate rows, starting the second duplicated row. So in your case, the first row of each group that exists in INC will be False, and the rest True, in the case that there is a merge between MDF and INC. If there is no merge happening, then `result[cols].isnull(...` will keep this row. It is how I understand the warning from your business